# IE Date.Parse() returns NaN

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to parse this string

"2017-06-01 11:22:20.683"

It is working just fine in Firefox, but return NaN in IE 11
Unfortunately I am unable to modify the source string since its coming from a legacy system.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var d = Date.parse("2017-06-01 11:22:20.683");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Maybe its because its not [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant. Try `"2017-06-01T11:22:20.683"` instead.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot modify the source.

Comment: Of course you can modify the string, you have it in javascript and can do anything you want to it. To say otherwise is just nonsense.

Comment: cannot modify the source date format, but I can code js/jquery around it to parse it in other ways...

Comment: unfortunately JavaScript dates are a little wonky in some browsers: officially it needs to support ISO8601 (and i think RFC2822 is by convention) [Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), but non-standard formats tend to be browser dependent, as @Dorival mentioned below [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) is very commonly used instead of the built in Date because it offers a standard way to represent Datetimes cross browser, and it supports more formats than Date does (it's also pretty good at guessing given a non-standard format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simpliest solution:

```
function myFunction(dateString) {
    var str = dateString.replace(/^(.*-[0-9][0-9])(\ )([0-9][0-9]\:.*$)/, '$1T$3')
    var d = Date.parse(str);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this API is not quite reliable. Edge still gives you a `NaN`. You have two options though:

1) Use an external library called MomentJS. Very easy to use and have all corner cases implemented. (http://momentjs.com/docs/)

2) Refer to this question to parse it manually: [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Please do not replace the '-' with '/', use whitespace instead.

```
var str = "15-Dec-2019 05:25:45 PM ";
console.log( Date.parse( str.replace(/-/g, ' ') ) );
```

This worked for me in Chrome and Firefox browsers, i hope, this will help you also.

Comment: output will be 1576410945000 in console panel of browser.

Answer (score -1):

```
/// Below example will work in All Browser including IE
<script>
 var selected_date = '2019,Apr,05'; // You need to change date format like this
 var parsing_date = Date.parse(selected_date.replace(/^(.*-[0-9][0-9])(\ )([0-9][0-9]\:.*$)/, '$1T$3'));
 alert(parsing_date); 
</script>
```

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer (almost) identical to this.